# How to extract numbers correctly from an input file in command line argument

Tags: visual-c++

I am attempting use ifstream to extract two numbers from a file in argv[1], named "inputFile", and the extracting operator seems to be extracting the bits of code rather than the numbers needed.

inputFile.txt was put into the command line operator by right clicking the project, going to properties -> debugging -> command arguments -> typing inputFile.txt into command arguments in visual studio 2017.

The file inputFile.txt is as below:

1 2

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <fstream>
  #include <string>
  #include <iomanip>

  using namespace std;

  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
  //Test opening file
  cout << "Input file: " << argv[1] << endl;
  ifstream in(argv[1]);
  if (!in)
  {
    cerr << "Unable to open " << argv[1] << " for input";
    return 1;
  }

      //extract numbers
  int num1;
  int num2;
  in >> num1 >> num2;

  cout << num1 << endl << num2 << endl;

  in.close();
  return 0;
}
```

I expect the int num1 to hold 1, and the int num2 to hold 2, but instead each variable holds the number -858993460.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure the file you are reading has got the data you expect? This code works fine for me, compiling with Visual Studio 2005. But, If I change the contents of the file, writing not numbers (for example if I write: a b), num1 and num2 ends with -858993460.